# Rails - Sass - 1p*x isn't a valid CSS value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I've got a strange error in Rails using Sass/Css:

**"1p*x isn't a valid CSS value."**

The application trace says it comes from:

app/assets/stylesheets/shared/form.css.scss:19

But in my file, this line is:

**"input{@include all_borders(1px, solid, red);}"**

It's like something is adding a " * " between p and x. And, it does the same issue with lot's of other lines. And... the error just came out, I never had it before, I didn't change anything in my config files, the only thing I did was to update my gems using bundle update.

**[Edit] The Mixin code:**

```
@mixin all_borders($strength: 1px, $type: solid, $color: black){
  border: $strength $type $color;
}
```

**[End Edit]**

I also have some "wrong number of arguments (4 for 1)" issues... But again, everything worked fine yesterday... It's like something is wrong with the precompilation of my scss files... I have the same issue when trying to precompile.

Does anyone have a clue? I don't know what to do...

If it may help: I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.3, sass 3.1.15 and sass-rails 3.2.5, I also post my application.rb & development.rb files:

**development.rb**
    config.cache_classes = false

```
config.whiny_nils = true

config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

config.active_support.deprecation = :log

config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

config.assets.compress = false
config.serve_static_assets = false

config.assets.debug = true
```

**application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
end

module MySite
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

    config.assets.version = '1.0'

  end
end
```

Thanks in advance for taking time to help me. :)

Comment: `all_borders` is a mixin that you've defined? What happens when you try to compile the Sass file directly? (the `:trace_selectors` option may be helpful here).

Comment: Yes it's a mixin I defined. But the error occurs even on common properties such as "margin". The compilation of the Sass file works fine, I managed to run this command: sass --watch input.scss:output.css without any errors when launching it and it does not add the " * " to the lines in the generated css file that Rails is pointing in the issue.

Comment: can you post the code from the actual mixin? It's possibly got a weavil in it

Comment: Hmm, very strange, that code works just fine as is, when I drop it into my own app. It's no fun when this happens.

Comment: One option is to run a search on your entire project for the string: `1p*x` in the hope that it has somehow slipped in somewhere without you noticing, perhaps when you closed your project down last night. Also, it might sound patronising, but try rebooting the machine

Comment: I managed to find what the problem was. But I can't post it yet, I have to wait 6 hours. Short description of the solution: I was creating a custom "to_a" method for the Ruby string class because the native one does not have it. This custom method was messing things up, as if some CSS related gems was already creating this method and using it for CSS compilation or related things. I'll post the answer tomorrow. By the way, thanks for the help. :) This problem was a really tough one to find - a custom string method messing things up in CSS is not the first thing you think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Okay I found what the problem was...** Pfiew, that was a tough one to find...

I had to create a whole new project, adding the code of my broken one, file by file and tracking the occurrence of the issue thanks to the Rails server.

So I discovered that deleting this file: 
*/config/initializers/custom_libraries.rb*

Was solving the issue. This file had only one line: **require 'ext/string'**

So the problem had to come from my custom string methods.

And yes it did. I was adding a "to_a" (to_array) method to the string class because the native Ruby string class doesn't have this method. The method was:

```
def to_a
  return self.chars.to_a
end
```

So commenting this method solved my CSS issues. I imagine that the sass-rails gem or CSS related ones is already creating this method and use it for compilation or other CSS stuff and my "to_a" string method surely messed things up. But I'm only guessing...

Surely the Rails errors weren't helpful at all to find this out. Does anyone know how I may have found the issue faster? Maybe a specific debug tool to recommend?

I will learn from this misadventure: never ever create your own method for a specific Ruby class with a name that is too similar with other Ruby class methods.